# Windows/Temp folder permission issue for IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have some applications hosted in IIS on windows 10. When I browse application from browser it shows: CS0016: Could not write to output file.........

What I have already tried is: I have set the Full Control permission for Network Service & IIS_USER for the Windows/Temp folder and the application runs as expected but after every restart of the machine the  permission get popped and I fall into the same error.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the issue you could try below steps:

1. Open iis manager
2. From the application pools select your site application pool
3. Click on the advance setting from action pane:

[image]

4)from the identity select network service:

[image]

5. click ok.

- Now go back and select site->  right click on a site and select edit permission

[image]

- Select the Security tab
- Click the Edit button and then Add button
- add iis_iusrs and iusr permission

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your step-by-step instructions. I did this before and found nothing helpful. Only Windows/Temp permission working properly and it refreshed after every restart/shutdown.

Comment: @MoloyAdhikary try running chkdsk /f on the disk, which will make sure the security information isn't corrupted. It should restore the directory to some 'standard' permissions.

If you're an administrator, you should be always able to take ownership using TAKEOWN /F C:\ /R /D Y

Once you have taken ownership, then you have to set the permissions; for this, you use ICACLS:

ICACLS "C:\" /reset /T